# Showing that a function attains maximum

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $u(x,t)$ and $v(y,t)$ be two continuous and bounded functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^d \times [0,T]$. Consider the quantity $u(x,t)-v(y,t)- \lambda |x-y|^2-\theta t$, defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2d} \times [0,T]$, does it attain its maxima if it exists? Here, $\lambda$ and $\theta$ are positive constants, $\theta$ is fixed, but $\lambda$ can be chosen as required.

As $u-v$ is bounded, say $u-v \le M$, for some $M>0$. We notice that $u-v- \lambda |x-y|^2-\theta t  \le M$ and it goes to $-\infty$ as $|x-y| \to \infty$. And a continuous function can only not attain its maxima if it approaches the maximum value at $\pm \infty$. Therefore the maxima exists at some point $(x_\lambda, y_\lambda, t_\lambda)$. I want to make it rigorous.

Comment: Does $\vert x - y \vert$ mean euclidean norm of $x - y$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: The $\sup$ exists, but it seems there are examples where it is not attainable. Consider $d = 1$ (the example can be generalized for arbitrary $d$) and $u(x, t) = \text{tanh}(x)$, $v(y,t) = - \text{tanh}(y)$. Then $\sup$ is approaching as $x = y \rightarrow +\infty$ and $t=0$

Comment: You are correct, $x$ and $y$ are canceling each other.